# jquery conflict - how to use the jQuery.noConflict();

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using JQuery for some drop down nav functionality. Worked great. Now I just added the Cycle JQuery Plugin and I can only get one to work at a time depending on which order I list them in the head. I have read about the jQuery.noConflict(); function but not really sure where to put it. Here is what I got.

HTML

```
<head>
    <title>#</title>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
    <meta content="online restaurant employee scheduling, employee scheduling, scheduling software, employee scheduling software,   restaurant scheduling, restaurant scheduling software, restaurant schedules, restaurant employee scheduling, online scheduling, online scheduling software" name="keywords"/>
    <meta content=" easy-to-use, Web-based restaurant labor management solutions and workforce management software offers flexible, effective and improved communication for employees and managers." name="description"/>
    <meta content="index, follow" name="robots"/>
    <meta content="no-cache" http-equiv="cache-control"/>
    <meta content="no-store" http-equiv="cache-control"/>
    <meta content="0" http-equiv="expires"/>
    <meta content="no-cache" http-equiv="pragma"/>
    <meta content="Rh52pxT6lFEqOVMlSt7QpOVHb325OHdlGkWZ0QMUSbU" name="google-site-verification"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/style.css" media="screen" />

    <script src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.cycle.all.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/menu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/slideshow.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
```

When it is structured like this my Cycle Plugin works but not the nav drop downs. Here are the corresponding .js files with the nav being: menu.js and the Cycle Plugin being: slideshow.js

menu.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {   

    $('#nav li').hover(  
        function () {  
            //show its submenu  
            $('ul', this).slideDown(100);  
        },   
        function () {  
            //hide its submenu  
            $('ul', this).slideUp(100);           
        }  
    );  

});
```

slideshow.js

```
$('#slideshow').cycle({ 
   speed:      200,
   timeout:    0, 
   pager:      '#tabs', 
   pagerEvent: 'mouseover' 
});
```

Comment: Is that the entire content of slideshow.js? If so, you might want to make it run after the page is loaded like menu.js does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see why you need `jQuery.noConflict()` which is to do with other scripts using the `$` variable. See the [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery.noConflict).

Instead, as Ryan says, you need to place your cycle code inside a `$(document).ready()`, so `slideshow.js` becomes:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $('#slideshow').cycle({ 
        speed:      200,
        timeout:    0, 
        pager:      '#tabs', 
        pagerEvent: 'mouseover' 
    });
});
```

Comment: So I did this and still nothing. I now have the slideshow.js as you indicate but only the slide show is working not the menu. What order would you have the scripts listed in the head?

Comment: It shouldn't make any difference what order they are listed in. Try constructing a minimal test page.

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation of noConflict()](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery.noConflict):

> NOTE: This function must be called
>   **after including the jQuery javascript
>   file, but before including any other
>   conflicting library**, and also before
>   actually that other conflicting
>   library gets used, in case jQuery is
>   included last. noConflict can be
>   called at the end of the jQuery.js
>   file to globally disable the $()
>   jQuery alias.

Just add a script tag to your header after your jquery includes to run the noConflict() function (example taken from the "[Using jQuery with noConflict](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries)" page):

```
<head>
   <script src="prototype.js"></script>
   <script src="jquery.js"></script>
   <script>
     jQuery.noConflict();

     // Use jQuery via jQuery(...)
     jQuery(document).ready(function(){
       jQuery("div").hide();
     });

     // Use Prototype with $(...), etc.
     $('someid').hide();
   </script>
 </head>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>jQuery.noConflict();</script>
<script src="js/jquery.cycle.all.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/menu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/slideshow.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

menu.js:

```
(function($){
$(document).ready(function () {   

    $('#nav li').hover(  
        function () {  
            //show its submenu  
            $('ul', this).slideDown(100);  
        },   
        function () {  
            //hide its submenu  
            $('ul', this).slideUp(100);           
        }  
    );  

}); 
})(jQuery);
```

slideshow.js:

```
(function($){

 $('blah').cycle()
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: thanks for answering. I did this as indicated and same result. Slideshow works but not menu doesn't. I am assuming that the 'blah' was just because I should understand it by that point in your answer but just want to make sure. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: can you make a separate question if you have an entirely different issue than the noConflict business? and provide html?